# How Set Some text merge and then to be clickable?

Tags: javascript, html

I try to merge two text in the left and right in left and create a clickable link.

```
                    <div class="mb-50">
                        <h2 class="section-title pr-0">Latest Topics on<span class="bold"> Blog</span><a
                                href="blog-right-sidebar.html" class="section-more right">OUR BLOG</a>
                        </h2>
                    </div>
```

I get this output:

[image]

How I can merge the left and right text together in the left in one hyperlink?

Update:

this is my last try and error:

[image]

```
<div class="mb-50">
                        <h2 class="section-title pr-0"><<a
                                href="blog-right-sidebar.html" class="section-more left">Latest Topics on </a> <span class="bold"> Blog</span>
                        </h2>
                    </div>
```

Update 2:

this is not the expected output because texts is placed on bottom !
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsDOS.png)

Comment: What is expected result and what have you tried?

Comment: now the right one is hyperlink I want the text "our blog" removed and "Latest..." be hyperlink @charlietfl and the pattern of left is remain

Comment: I try to exchange <a> tag in <span> but at most I get error @charlietfl

Comment: What error and from what code? Objective here is for others to help fix your attempts to solve your own issue, not to be a free code writing service

Comment: @charlietfl see my updates and error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the href tag encapsulates all of the text that you want it to link. For example, I did this and it links to the site when any of the text is clicked.

`<div class="mb-50">
   <h2 class="section-title pr-0">
     <a href="blog-right-sidebar.html" class="section-more left">Latest Topics on <span 
       class="bold"> Blog</span>
     </a> 
   </h2>
 </div>`

On your second attempt, you capped the href off at the end of "Latest Topics on ", so it only redirects to the link upon clicking "Latest Topics on ", cutting off " Blog".

Hope that helped!

Comment: your output wrote "latest..." on the bottom of line (my code output this text in center) !

Comment: Can I see the CSS for your attempts?

Comment: Which part of CSS files? style? bootstrap/? or ...?

Comment: The different class elements that are listed. "mb-50", "section-title pr-0", "blog-right-sidebar.html", "section-more left", and "bold"

Comment: .sm-mb-50 {
    margin-bottom: 50px
}

Comment: .section-title,
.section-title-2 {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #4b4e53
}

Comment: .bold {
    font-weight: 700
}

Comment: I'm not getting the same results, are there any other divs around the one listed?

Comment: before these line I have:
<div id="blog-link" class="page-section pt-110-b-30-cont">
                <div class="container">

Comment: <div class="mb-50">
                        <h2 class="section-title pr-0">Latest News on<a
                                href="blog-right-sidebar.html"><span class="bold"> OUR BLOG </span></a>
                        </h2>
                    </div>

Comment: I'll also need the CSS for "blog-link" "page-section pt-110-b-30-cont" and "container"